# NSPredicate CKReference is not user ID

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to make a cloud kit nspredicate that will return all items where forSale(Int) == 1 and ownerRecord(CKRefereance) != the current user's record.
Here is what I have:

```
let Query = CKQuery(recordType: "Item", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "ownerRecord.recordID != %@, forSale = 1", [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cloudkitUserReccordID") as! String]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for a reference and not for a recordId string. Your could would then look something like:

```
let ownerId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cloudkitUserReccordID") as! String
let ownerRef = CKReference(recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: ownerId), action: CKReferenceAction.None)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ownerRecord != %@, forSale = 1", ownerRef)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Item", predicate: predicate))
```

Comment: This dose not seem to work           *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ownerRecord != %@, forSale = 1"'